# Copy Cells Greater than Zero, and Paste Values in same Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that is filled with formulas tied to another sheet. These formulas grab data from the other table based on whether the date at the top of the column matches the date in a single cell (Week Ending Date). I want to be able to automatically copy only the cells with a value greater than 0, and then paste them back into the same cell as a value. I used the following formula to try and accomplish this, but it didn't quite do what I wanted it to. Be gentle, I'm a novice at best.

```
Sub CopyC()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("Table4")
For Each cel In SrchRng
    If cel.Value > 0 Then
        cel.Copy
    cel.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Expected Output: Copy only Cells in my table that are greater than 0 and paste as value.

Goal: Preserve Formulas in cells that are blank

Results from above: Very slowly progressed cell by cell and copied and pasted in all cells, including blanks and 0 values, until it was stopped

Comment: I ran this with a test file of 2k formulas with a simple K1*L1 formula and it ran fast and did exactly how you want it to.    Maybe you could post an example of the data and formula?   How many rows are in Table4?

Comment: `cel.Value > 0` checks against strings as well, which are... well, greater than 0.

Comment: @mooseman, if it wasn't proprietary I definitely would've shared the table I'm working with. FAB's suggestion worked great though. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```vb
Sub CopyC()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("Table4")
For Each cel In SrchRng
    If IsNumeric(cel.Value) And cel.Value > 0 Then
        cel.Value = cel.Value
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** add an alternative using an array to loop through the data, this should be a bit faster:

```vb
Sub CopyC()

Dim SrchRng As Range: Set SrchRng = Range("Table4")
Dim arrSearch As Variant: arrSearch = SrchRng

Dim fRow As Long: fRow = SrchRng.Cells(1, 1).Row - 1
Dim fCol As Long: fCol = SrchRng.Cells(1, 1).Column - 1
Dim R As Long, C As Long

For R = LBound(arrSearch) To UBound(arrSearch)
    For C = LBound(arrSearch, 2) To UBound(arrSearch, 2)
        If IsNumeric(arrSearch(R, C)) And arrSearch(R, C) > 0 Then Cells(R + fRow, C + fCol).Value = arrSearch(R, C)
    Next C
Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly @FAB! Felt like I was beating my head off a wall. Glad I asked for help. Thank you!

Comment: I used the array option just FYI